# Google Visualization Dashboard Table page button styling

Tags: google-visualization

I can't seem to find a way to style the page buttons on a dashboard table.  I want to make the page buttons at the bottom of the table bigger if that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try increasing the `font-size`

add the following CSS...

```
.google-visualization-table-page-number {
  font-size: 16px !important;
}
```